# Await a grandparent component's method to be resolved in grandchild component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have three components in my vue application:

- Home: (Button's grandparent)
- Dialog: (Home's child / Button's parent)
- Button: (Home's grandchild)

The `Home` component has a async method:

```
async handleDialogAccept() {
  try {
    const response = await this.$axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/');
    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
},
```

And it will executed as soon as the `Dialog` component emits the "accept" custom event:

```
<dialog-confirmation
  @accept="handleDialogAccept()"
/>
```

The `Dialog` component has a child (`Button`):

```
<button-accept
  v-on="$listeners"
>
  Accept
</button-accept>
```

In my `buttonAccept.vue` which is being imported in the `Dialog` and used as shown above has the next structure:

```
<template>
  <v-btn
    color="primary"
    @click="handleClick()"
    :loading="loading"
    :disabled="loading"
  >
    <slot name="accept"></slot>
  </v-btn>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['parentFunction'],
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick() {
      this.$emit('accept');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I will like to execute the next steps inside the `handleClick` method:

1. Set `loading` to true
2. Emit the accept custom event
3. Wait until the `handleDialogAccept` is done
4. Set `loading` to false

Is there a wait to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, you can define a variable (`isAcceptDone`) in `Home` component to determine whether the async method is done or not in the `Button` component.

The `Home` component

```
async handleDialogAccept() {
  try {
    const response = await this.$axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/');
    console.log(response.data);
    this.isAcceptDone = true;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
},
```

The `Dialog` component

```
<dialog-confirmation
  @accept="handleDialogAccept()"
  :isAcceptDone="isAcceptDone"
/>
```

The `Button` component

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['parentFunction', 'isAcceptDone'],
    data() {
      return {
        loading: false,
      };
    },
    watch: {
      isAcceptDone(val) {
         if(val) {
           this.loading = false
         }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      handleClick() {
        this.$emit('accept');
      },
    }
 };
</script>
```

On the other hand, If you thought it is too complicated to pass `isAcceptDone` in three components. Using EventBus is another simple ways.

Comment: I'll give a try to the event bus suggestion. Thanks for your answer!